# How to get whole types that is used in a class with Roslyn? (all nested/inner types recursively)

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, roslyn

Please consider this sample:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Age { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public IInterface MyInterface { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string[] Phones { get; set; }
    public MyEnum E1  { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public Dictionary<decimal, Address> A1 { get; set; }
    public Collection<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Tuple<double, BigInteger> A2 { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
   En1,
   En2
}
```

As you see, I want to get all inner classes/structs/types of `Person` 
so the result is :

`Person.GetInnerTypes():`

```
Guid
float
string
IInterface
Address
string[]
MyEnum
Job
List<Address>
IEnumerable<Job>
Dictionary<decimal, Address>
decimal
Collection<DateTime>
DateTime
Tuple<double, BigInteger>
double
BigInteger
```

The types are collected from everywhere (properties, arguments,...)

Is it possible to find whole types (recursively) by Roslyn? 
Does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT:**

Why do I need this?

The problem comes from creating a code generator, if you see the [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) library you should define rules for every type at first then create the main rule for Person class so I need to know all types for a class to create a code generator for generating test data! (generate a working class)

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

Comment: Those are not inner classes. Those are types being used in the class definition. Also this is quite vague. Would you count locals in blocks as well? This would *probably* be easiest by visiting the AST, instead of doing it at the symbol level. Depending on whether you can do that or not.

Comment: float, double, decimal and Guid are not classes. By "whole" do you  mean "all"?

Comment: @Joey I have no idea see my edit section

Comment: @olivier-jacot-descombes Yes I know that no problem I need them too for creating test data generator class by a code generator !

Comment: Do you really need to to it with Roslyn or could you use Reflection as well? Note: Roslyn works on source code while Reflection works on compiled code.

Comment: I wrote that with reflection with a recursive method but is not reliable. I prefer Roslyn but If you have any idea even with reflection would be great but Do you handle all args types of a Tuple or Dictionary,... with that?

Comment: Both reflection and recursion are reliable (as long as you're careful to handle circular dependencies).  What is the problem?

Comment: @SLaks My code is not! I have no problem yet but I don't know that works in any scenario so I want to find a Roslyn way by who know that. this is my code https://gist.github.com/HamedFathi/4b75955ecb18190f512de62724dcdf0b

Answer (score 1):

That's a very broad answer.
If you are interested in the properteis only - just use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436368/how-to-get-method-definition-using-roslyn?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question. Find your class' DeclarationSyntax, then find all DescendantNodes of PropertyDeclarationSyntax type. PropertyDeclarationSyntax will give you access to types, and you will go into recursion (don't forget about loops). **This should be enough for a prototype.**

Even on this step you should be careful with

1. Nested classes. Types used there will be included into your list too.
2. Generics. Sometime there are limitations like Type where T : ISomeInterface. Also, nested Generics.
3. Partial classes
4. Is Func < T1, T2> the same with Func< T2, T1> for you?

After all, there are questions about your problem itself.

1. Do you need parents of used types?
2. Do you care about properties only, or methods\fields\events etc are valuable also?
3. Should you think about properties inherited from the parents?
4. If you care about methods - should you think about parameters types?
5. If you care about methods - should you think about variables defined inside?

**Edit1.**
Maybe reflection is enough for your task?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var properties = typeof(DemoPerson).GetProperties();
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Property: {property.Name}\tType: {property.PropertyType}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class DemoPerson
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }            
        public List<DemoAddress> Addresses { get; set; }            
    }

    public class DemoAddress
    {
        public string City { get; set; }            
    }
```

With output

Property: Id    Type: System.Guid

Property: Name  Type: System.String

Property: Addresses Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DemoInnerTypes.Program+DemoAddress]

Comment: This is based on test data generator library, Suppose You want to generate some classes some test data generator classes. Af first you want to know about all types second you should define your rules for those types so the answer is based on How does library work? for Bogus I think I should get all properties types not more.

Comment: Do you have an idea for generating test data generator classes ? for a total solution code generator I need to generate them.

Comment: So, let me clarify. You want to create a test Generator, which gets a type - and returns an instance of this type with random values. 
So, if you have a public class Foo { public string Bar { get;set;}}, you want to invoke Foo result = MyCodeGenerator.Generate<Foo>(); and get a result like result.Bar = "SomeRandomString". Correct?

Comment: I want to generate some .cs files. C# files have all need to use as test data generator so If I want to generate those files I should know about all types then define rules for all. please see https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus samples. Suppose you want to create some .cs files with those content. I want to create csharp sources for Bogus in my example You should know about Job and Address first because they used in Person then You should define rules for them, at last, you can generate test data files for Person. Final result is some correct and compilable cs files for generate test data.

Comment: Still can't understand what exactly do you want. Could you write the simplest example of (input, desired output) in the question under the Edit2, please?

Comment: See new picture I generated a source code based on https://objectfillernet.readme.io/ library.